# Apple Mail does not seem to connect to my IMAP server

Tags: network, mail.app, imap

I have my own Mailhosting, and am moving servers. Thunderbird works fine with the new Server IP. However, Apple Mail seems to fail and to silently ignore the new server.

I am using Courier IMAP and watching its log messages. When Thunderbird connects, I can see the successfull login. Apple Mail's activity window and network window shows a lot of stuff as well, but Courier keeps silent. Apple Mail then complains that it cannot connect. This is the only message I get in Apple Mail regarding the IMAP connection:

```
INITIATING CONNECTION Dec 28 18:15:53.727 [kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNone] -- host:myhostname.com -- port:143 -- socket:0x6000004c4210 -- thread:0x600000666340
```

For some reason, the connection is never mentioned again, and the signal in the network diagnosis goes "red" very quickly.

Any ideas what Mail is doing differently, compared to Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a followup: I solved my problem by doing the following steps:

1. Delete the account from Mail.app
2. Quit Mail.app
3. Delete `/Users/$USER/Library/Mail/V2/IMAP-yourmail@something.com`, if it still exists
4. Start Mail.app and re-create the account

After that, I could use the IMAP account just fine.